# Android - distinguish ViewGroup click and child View long click

Tags: android, android-touch-event

I have a ViewGroup with a click listener, and I can detect clicks easily. But when I add child views with a long click listeners - it "steals" the clicks and prevent the ViewGroup to intercept the short click. So is there an easy way to fix this issue, or I need to go with the dreadful path of interceptTouchEvent stuff.

Comment: Using onInterceptTouchEvent may be easier but you may also try to call `(childView.parent as View).performClick()` in both `onClickListener` and `onLongClickListener` of the child view.

Comment: @ocos Thank you that's exactly what I did and it works